# IntelliJ Grails project not seeing /src/main/groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, grails

```
Versions 
IntelliJ 2021.1.2
Grails 4.0.10
JVM 11.0.2
```

Grails works and can see the source in /src/main/groovy just fine but IntelliJ can not. I see the following error "Cannot resolve symbol 'SamConfig'". SamConfig is a simple groovy class for holding configuration.

The src/main folder is set up as a SourceFolder in the parent module of the project. The grails-app is a submodule called main. Please let me know if I can provide any more details to help solve this issue.
Thanks

Larry

Answer (score 0):

> The src/main folder is set up as a SourceFolder in the parent module
> of the project.

You should set `src/main/groovy`/ to be a source root, not `src/main/`.

Comment: all I could do to make it work is to make a src folder in grails-app directory

Comment: "all I could do to make it work is to make a src folder in grails-app directory" - That is definitely not required.  If you would like some help looking at it you can submit the free consultation form at https://objectcomputing.com/products/grails and we can jump on a screen share to straighten it out.  I am quite sure it is something trivial in the project config causing an issue.  I have worked on probably 100s of Grails apps and none of them have a `grails-app/src/` folder.